# Is It possible to find out what are the common part in String List

Tags: c#, string

I was working on finding out the Common string part in the String list. If we take a sample data set

```
private readonly List<string> Xpath = new List<string>()
{   
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(1)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(2)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(4)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(5)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(6)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(7)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(8)>H2:nth-of-type(1)",
    "BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>SECTION:nth-of-type(9)>H2:nth-of-type(1)"
};
```

From this, I want to find out to which children these are similar. data is an Xpath list.
Programmatically I should be able to tell

Expected output:

> BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV

In order to get this What I did was like this. I separate each item by `>` and then create a list of items for each dataset originally.

Then using this find out what are the unique items

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetCommonItems<T>(IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    HashSet<T> hs = new HashSet<T>(lists.First());
    for (int i = 1; i < lists.Length; i++)
    {
        hs.IntersectWith(lists[i]);
    }
    return hs;
}
```

Able to find out the unique values and create a dataset again. But what happened is if this contains Ex:- Div in two places and it also in every originally dataset even then this method will pick up only one Div.

From then I would get something like this:

> BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION

But I need this

> BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-
> type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/discuss/6924/Sorted-the-array-Java-solution-2-ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is not the most performant solution but it works :)

- Let's start with splitting the first path by `>` character
- Do the same with all the paths

```
char separator = '>';
IEnumerable<string> firstPathChunks = Xpath[0].Split(separator);
var chunks = Xpath.Select(path => path.Split(separator).ToList()).ToArray();
```

- Iterate through the `firstPathChunks`

  - Iterate through the `chunks`
  - if there is a match then remove the first element
  - if all first element is removed then append the matching prefix to `sb`

```
void Process(StringBuilder sb)
{
    foreach (var pathChunk in firstPathChunks)
    {
        foreach (var chunk in chunks)
        {
            if (chunk[0] != pathChunk)
            {
                return;
            }
            chunk.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        sb.Append(pathChunk); 
        sb.Append(separator);
    }
}
```

Sample usage

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
Process(sb);
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

---

Output

```
BODY>MAIN:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(1)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the string by the seperator `>` is a good idea. Instead of then creating a list of unique items you should create a list of all items contained in the string which would result in

```
{
    "BODY",
    "MAIN:nth-of-type(1)",
    "DIV",
    "SECTTION",
    "DIV",
    ...
}
```

for the first entry of your XPath list.

This way you create a `List<List<string>>` containing every element of each entry of your XPath list. You then can compare all first elements of the inner lists. If they are equal save that elements value to you output and proceed with all second elements and so on until you find an element that is not equal in all outer lists.

Edit:
After seperating your list by the `>` seperator this could look something like this:

```
    List<List<string>> XPathElementsLists;
    List<string> resultElements = new List<string>();
    string result;

    XPathElementsLists = ParseElementsFormXPath(XPath);

    for (int i = 0; i < XPathElementsLists[0].Count; i++)
    {
        bool isEqual = true;
        string compareElemment = XPathElementsLists[0][i];
        foreach (List<string> element in XPathElementsLists)
        {
            if (!String.Equals(compareElemment, element))
            {
                isEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isEqual)
        {
            break;
        }
        resultElements.Add(compareElemment);
    }

    result = String.Join(">", resultElements.ToArray());
```